# Get char bounding boxes and confidence levels in ABBYY SDK

Tags: c++, abbyy

I convert an image using ABBYY's OCR SDK:

```
CSafePtr<IFRDocument> frDocument = ...;
frDocument->AddImageFile( "C:\\test\\input.tif" );
frDocument->Process( 0 );
frDocument->Export( "C:\\test\\output.rtf", FEF_RTF, 0  );
```

But now I need to get the char bounding boxes and confidence levels, as well. I can get them from Tesseract so I assume it's possible with ABBYY's SDK as well.

How do I get the bounding boxes and confidence levels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I eventually found how to do it, you need to use the `IPlainText::GetCharacterData()`.

> GetCharacterData Method of the PlainText Object
>   This method returns the information about all characters in the text as a set of arrays: the page numbers on which the characters are located, the coordinates of characters' rectangles, and characters' confidences.

Example:

```
CSafePtr<IPlainText> plainText;
frDocument->get_PlainText(&plainText);
SAFEARRAY *confidences, *pageNumbers, *leftBorders, *topBorders, *rightBorders, *bottomBorders, *isSuspicious;
plainText->GetCharacterData(&pageNumbers, &leftBorders, &topBorders, &rightBorders, &bottomBorders, &confidences, &isSuspicious);
```